# AWS No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'name-env'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Why might I be seeing this error after I run `git aws.push`?

```
remote: error: Unable to deploy application version: No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'reco-api-env'.
```

When I grep my flask app's directory for `EnvironmentName`, I see this:

```
./.elasticbeanstalk/config:6:EnvironmentName=name-env
./.git/AWSDevTools/aws/elastic_beanstalk_config.rb:36:      :environment_name => "EnvironmentName",
```

Answer (score 6):

I had similar symptoms when I manually updated `default_region` from `us-west-2` to `us-west-1`. Reverting back fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you missed a step in [the process](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html). You need to use `eb start` before doing `git aws.push`.

Answer (score 2):

I was using eb create to setup a new environment where the name differed from what I had started with in /.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml

Once I updated the environment reference to the one one I meant to target, eb commands started working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too. For me, it was because I had outdated credentials in my ~/.aws/config file. Fixing that solved the problem.

Comment: link to how to do this?